# ASCII vs UTF-8?

Tags: python, encoding

Assuming the storage size is important: 
I have a long list of digits (0-9) that I want to write to a file. From a storage standpoint, would it be more efficient to use ASCII or UTF-8 as an encoding? 
Is it possible to create a smaller file using something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference between ASCII and UTF-8 when storing digits. A tighter packing would be using 4 bits per digit ([BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)).

If you want to go below that, you need to take advantage of the fact that long sequences of 10-base values can be presented as 2-base (binary) values.

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely no difference in this case; UTF-8 is identical to ASCII in this character range.

If storage is an important consideration, maybe look into compression. A simple Huffman compression will use something like 3 bits per byte for this kind of data. If there are periodicity patterns, a modern compression algorithm can take it even further.